# List of non-zero elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

Given the list

```
a = [6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

What is the best way in Python to return the list

```
b = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

where the 1's in b correspond to the non-zero elements in a. I can think of running a for loop and simply appending onto b, but I'm sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

List comprehension method:

```
a = [6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
b = [1 if i else 0 for i in a]
print b
>>> 
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

---

Timing mine, [Dave's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16775401/1561176) and [Lattyware's slight alteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775379/list-of-non-zero-elements-in-a-list-in-python#comment24170675_16775401):

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "a = [6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]" "[1 if i else 0 for i in a]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.838 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s "a = [6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]" "[int(i != 0) for i in a]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.15 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s "a = [6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]" "[i != 0 for i in a]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.794 usec per loop
```

Looks like my method is twice as fast ... I am actually surprised it is *that* much faster. Taking out the `int()` call, however, makes the two essentially the same - but leaves the resulting list full of `Booleans` instead of `Integers` (True/False instead of 1/0)

Comment: That is not a good way to time Python code snippets. Use the `timeit` module.

Comment: because you don't have casting but also because your else clause is evaluated only once in your example

Comment: @Lattyware You are absolutely right. I just hate that module. Feel free to edit my answer with a better timeit regiment. :)

Comment: @InbarRose Why do you hate the module?

Comment: @Lattyware That is a long story - come to the Python Chat Room if you want.

Comment: A bit of nitpicking: `False` and `[]` are non zero values, but would produce a `0` in your code. Why not make explicit what you want to have: `1 if i!=0 else 0`?

Answer (score 5):

```
b = [int(i != 0) for i in a]
```

Will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: It's worth noting that `True == 1` and `False == 0`, so just `[i != 0 for i in a]` will work fine, so long as you don't mind the representation being different (that is, it will produce `[True, True, False, False, True, False]`, but that will function the same as the requested list).

Comment: @Lattyware absolutely, just trying to match the OP's desired output.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, and since no one else added this answer:

```
b = map(bool, a)
```

But it returns Boolean values and not Integers.

Comment: It's worth noting that in 3.x, this returns a generator, not a list (naturally, this can be changed - if necessary, by wrapping with a call to `list()`).

Comment: +1 This works fine,  returning `Boolean` values makes more sense than plain integers you should add this to timings

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
>>> a = [6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]

>>> [bool(x) for x in a]
[True, True, False, False, True, False]

>>> [int(bool(x)) for x in a]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Depending what you want it for, you might be better with the boolean list.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
>>> a = [6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]

>>> [cmp(x,0) for x in a]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Note that `cmp(x,0)` returns -1 for negative  numbers, so you might want to `abs` that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also, depending on your application, work with numpy array representation:

```
$ import numpy as np
$ a = [6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
$ (np.array(a)!= 0).astype(int)
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

astype(int) is only necessary if you dont't want a boolean representation

Answer (score 0):

And for the heck of it, another way:

```
[{0: 0}.get (el, 1) for el in your_list]
```